# Docker Compose not starting

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, microservices

My `docker-compose.yml` file contains

```
version: '2'
 services:
   config-server:
     image: config-server
   registration-server:
     image: registration-server
     ports:
       - 1111:1111
```

Config server Docker file is

```
FROM java:8-jre
MAINTAINER ccc <cccc.@vv.com>

ADD ./target/config-server.jar /app/
CMD ["java", "-Xmx200m", "-jar", "/app/config-server.jar"]

EXPOSE 1116
```

and my registration server Dockerfile is

```
FROM java:8-jre
MAINTAINER ccc <cccs.@gg.com>

ADD ./target/registration-server.jar /app/
CMD ["java", "-Xmx200m", "-jar", "/app/registration-server.jar"]

EXPOSE 1111
```

While I am starting this Docker Compose it's showing

```
Creating registration-server
creating config-server
```

After that it's not showing when I am checking in Docker. However, while typing `docker ps -a` it shows status `exited(0)`.

Comment: You can use `docker logs <containter>` to see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can only debug this by seeing what happened during the container launch. Use `docker logs <container_name>` to view the logs from the container that failed to launch.

Just at first glance, your `ports` directive should be wrapping ports in strings:

```
ports
  - "1111:1111"
```

Also, it's safer to use unreserved port numbers, typically above 2000 on most OSes.